# Does a cube even make sense for this type of data?

Tags: ssas, olap

Most articles about OLAP are written with a transactional system in mind (think customers/orders).  And the few that aren't like that, specifically those that explain 'factless fact tables' are usually based around some kind of event, see http://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/factless-fact-table.html

What about databases that only house demographic data?  For example, one table with a customer id, and several related tables each with one customer attributes such as citizenship, age, etc.

If I want to create a model where the user can slice and aggregate on these extended customer attributes, does it even make sense to build a cube, or is that the wrong tool for the job?

Would the citizenship table be a dimension and the customer table be a fact?

Answer (score 0):

What numeric fact are you aggregating? The only thing you can aggregate here is the count. Generally without some kind of numeric fact to aggregate there really isn't much you can analyse in OLAP except for drilling up/down dimensions. In this case it's more of a data discovery function